# Aligning Axes Handle Within UIPanel Programatically - Matlab

Tags: matlab, uicontrol

I'm having problems aligning an `axes_h` handle within a `uipanel`.  I want to be able to give my plot a specific size, then center it in the middle of the panel, then hopefully align my `uipanel` with my figure subsequently.  I've looked at the documentation and the example only aligns and distributes `uicontrol` buttons within a `figure`.

Here is my code:

```
%% create figure
fig_h = figure;
set(fig_h, 'Position', [100, 100, 1049, 895]);

%% create empty scatter plot within a panel
e_panel_position = [0.1 0.4 0.4 0.5];
e_panel_h = uipanel('Parent', fig_h, 'Title','Emotion','FontSize',12,'BackgroundColor','white','Position',e_panel_position);

axes_position = [0 0 0.7 0.8];
axes_h = axes('Parent', e_panel_h, 'Position', axes_position);
scatter_h = scatter(axes_h, [],[], 'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 .5 .5], 'MarkerFaceColor',[0 .7 .7],'LineWidth',1.5);
axis(axes_h, [-4 4 -4 4]);
align(axes_h, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'Center', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Middle');
```

EDIT:

I'm struggling to get two static text boxes and a slider to align in a straight line using the `align` function.  I want the first text box to be in front of the slider and the second text box to be the other side of the slider like so:

[image: slider]

Then I would like to be able to take a handle from the align object and perform the centering method that 'Will' has suggested below to center all three items as a collective group.  The image illustrates this, but it is very fiddly to do, since I did this manually.  However, I need to do this for many more sliders within many more `uipanel` boxes, so I figured this would be a quicker method.

Here is my code:

```
%% create environment slider and text with panel
env_panel_position = [0.1 0.33 0.4 0.1];
env_panel_h = uipanel('Parent', fig_h, 'Title','Environment','FontSize',12,'BackgroundColor','white','Position',env_panel_position);

dark_text_position = [0 0 0.1 0.3];
dry_text_h = uicontrol('Parent', env_panel_h, 'Style', 'text', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', dark_text_position, 'String', 'dark');

dark_light_slider_position = [0 0 0.7 0.1];
dark_light_slider_h = uicontrol('Parent', env_panel_h, 'Style', 'slider', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', dark_light_slider_position);

wet_text_position = [0 0 0.1 0.3];
wet_text_h = uicontrol('Parent', env_panel_h, 'Style', 'text', 'units', 'normalized', 'position', wet_text_position, 'String', 'Light');

align_h = align([dry_text_h dark_light_slider_h wet_text_h], 'Distribute', 'Middle');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `align` function position *multiple objects* so they are *in line*. To center a graphics object within its container you just need to give it the correct position in `normalized` units, which is the default for the objects you're creating.

Your definition `axes_position = [0 0 0.7 0.8];` means `axes_h` has a width 70% of the uipanel, and 80% of its height. To centre it, you just need to set the bottom left coordinate to be 15% of the way across and 10% of the way up the container:

```
axes_position = [0.15 0.1 0.7 0.8];
```

The same works for the positioning of the uipanel:

```
e_panel_position = [0.3 0.25 0.4 0.5];
```

Comment: That makes sense and is something I need to tackle next since I need to place a few `slider` objects within another `uipanel` and align them appropriately.  I understand your first example, which I have implemented already, but I am struggling to work out how to apply it to other objects of others sizes i.e. you have `0.3` and `0.25` for the `e_panel_position`? What are we doing in terms of the maths to work this out?

Comment: The generic calculation is `h.Position(1:2) = (1-h.Position(3:4))/2`. A centered object has equal amounts of space on either side of it. The total amount of space in the container has a normalized length of 1, so the left/bottom coordinates need to be half what's left over after you've subtracted the width/height.

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense now.  Sorry, but I have edited my post as I have subsequently tried to align three objects in a straight line with no success.  Is it possible you can help me further?

Comment: Using `align` with the `Distribute` option preserves the extremes of the controls you're aligning, so you'd still have to position the right hand text correctly. Your current example sets them up as overlapping, so the effect is just to "even up" the amount of overlap.

With more complex layouts like this, to avoid hand-writing the calculations your best bet is the [GUI Layout Toolbox](http://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47982-gui-layout-toolbox) (developed by MathWorks) which lets you organize the controls in a way that more directly reflects your intent.